# VirtualBox Mac OS X High Sierra guest crashes when connecting iPhone device with USB passthrough

Tags: mac, usb, virtualbox, iphone

I am running Mac OS X in VirtualBox (no, this question is NOT off-topic [1](https://meta.superuser.com/a/2405/293360) [2](https://meta.superuser.com/q/12050/293360)). When I connect my iPhone 5S to the virtual machine through USB passthrough, the virtual machine crashes, the VirtualBox interface freezes and I have to kill it and my iPhone reboots.

I have installed VirtualBox guest extensions 5.2.6. I have set USB controller to USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller in VM's options.

This only happens in Mac OS X guests, I can use USB passthrough just fine in Ubuntu guests. Also this only happens with an iPhone device, my Android device connects to guest just fine.

- Arch Linux host
- VirtualBox 5.2.6 r120293 (latest version)
- Mac OS X High Sierra 10.13 guest (latest version)
- iPhone 5S iOS 11 (latest version)

VirtualBox logs after crash:

```
00:00:16.685265 NAT: IPv6 not supported
00:01:05.173008 VUSB: Attached '00007f6107126f80[proxy 05ac:12a8]' to port 1 on RootHub#0 (HighSpeed)
00:01:05.177304 EHCI: USB Operational
00:01:05.409305 VUSB: Detached '00007f6107126f80[proxy 05ac:12a8]' from port 1 on RootHub#0
00:01:05.570716 EHCI: USB Suspended
00:04:18.560308 VUSB: Attached '00007f6107128500[proxy 05ac:12a8]' to port 1 on RootHub#0 (HighSpeed)
00:04:18.563339 EHCI: USB Operational
00:04:27.076584 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005) aIID={ee35adb0-4748-3e12-e7fd-5aad957bba0f} aComponent={MouseWrap} aText={Could not send the mouse event to the virtual mouse (VERR_PDM_NO_QUEUE_ITEMS)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:04:42.137677 VUSB: Detached '00007f6107128500[proxy 05ac:12a8]' from port 1 on RootHub#0
```

dmesg logs during crash:

```
[ 5173.299990] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 10
[ 5173.306217] EhciFramer[11867]: segfault at 3 ip 00007f60e5e89052 sp 00007f60d5ca8ac0 error 4 in VBoxDD.so[7f60e5dda000+1b1000]
[ 5173.322524] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ncm
[ 5173.327148] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_wdm
[ 5173.329825] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_mbim
```

Comment: there are no Guest Additions for macOS, so it's not truly surprising. Maybe use Parallels instead, for which full support is provided. *edit* Ahh, sorry, you're not running it on a Mac... therefore it's off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the use of OSX on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Comment: Please don't close vote this, because Hackintosh questions are NOT off-topic here, see https://meta.superuser.com/q/12050/293360

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes there are no guest additions for mac but it has nothing to do with usb passthrough, as my Android phone and any other usb device works just fine through usb passthrough without guest additions.

Comment: Please read the [highest-voted answer](https://meta.superuser.com/a/12052/213131) on the 2nd Meta question you linked. It explains why this question is being closed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user is trying to do something that's simply not possible without being an Apple/$(Hardware Vendor) device driver engineer.

Comment: @Twisty Impersonator I have read that answer. Why do you think what I am doing is not possible? Mac OS X does ship with an Iphone driver. Other people have done this successfully in the past.

Answer (score 0):

According to VirtualBox documentation this is not supported:

Read section "14.2. Known Issues":

> VirtualBox does not provide Guest Additions for Mac OS X at this time.

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch14.html

**SOLUTION:**

Try using VMWare player instead. Be sure to install VMWare tools in the guest.

Comment: Yes Mac guests are not officially supported by any hypervisor. However guest additions have nothing to do with USB passthrough: I can do USB passthrough on any other device just fine, except for an iPhone. Also I have tried using VMWare, but it exhibits the same problem, even with guest additions installed.

Comment: You will have to develop your own pass-through driver.